# Java: I can't change the background of JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Greeting everyone. I've working a java program. I want to change the background of a JButton,However I can't change it. When the function is over, the color doesn't change a little.Here is my Code:

```
public void initialization() {
        button = new JButton[size][size];
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, size));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                button[i][j] = new JButton();
                button[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                //button[i][j].setVisible(true);
                //button[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                mainPanel.add(button[i][j]);

            }
        }
        mainPanel.updateUI();
        System.out.print("Button Finished\n");
    }
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to set it opaque before changing background:

```
button[i][j].setOpaque(true);
button[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Yeah!That's the key! Thank you! I will mark it as the correct in 8 mins. The system doesn't allow me to do this within 8 mins.